# Adding column check to a Unique Value Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have this function I use to loop through a range and count how many unique values there are:

```
    Function CountUniqueValues(InputRange As Range) As Long
       Dim cl As Range, UniqueValues As New Collection
       Application.Volatile
       On Error Resume Next
       For Each cl In InputRange
            UniqueValues.Add cl.Value, CStr(cl.Value) 
       Next cl
       On Error GoTo 0
       CountUniqueValues = UniqueValues.Count
    End Function

   CountUniqueValues(Range("B1:B100"))
```

I need to add in the for loop a check to another column:

```
If A1 = "P" Then
   UniqueValues.Add cl.Value, CStr(cl.Value)
End If
```

Obviously col A would have to increment as col B does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
If Range("A" & c1.Row) = "P" Then
```

Comment: I get an error of 'Application-defined or object-define error'...is it because I just have Range or ActiveSheet.Range used in a Function?